# Как управлять KeyAutoReat?

Tags: qt

Кто-нибудь знает как управлять `autoRepeat'ом` клавиши клавиатуры на `Qt`? Как отключить `autoRepeat` или как изменить задержку её начала?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать QApplication::keyboardInputInterval (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#keyboardInputInterval-prop), а также  свойство QShortcut::autoRepeat.

Comment: Спасибо. Достиг нужного результата с помощью autoRepeat

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Не забудьте отметить ответ принятым) Успехов!